# Typesetting ":-" in Latex

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know what is the Latex incantation corresponding to ":-". I tried detexifying but I can't find anything. Thanks !

Comment: Can you tell us *how* `:-` or `$:-$` are insufficient?  Perhaps `$\vcenter{\hbox{:}}-$` would suit your needs.

Comment: The `mathtools` package provides this symbol as `\coloneq`.

Comment: @IanThompson Isn't `\coloneq` with an `=` instead of a `-`, as requested by the OP?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes --- no, that's `\coloneqq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the spacing when used in formulas? Look here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
a :- b

$a :- b$

$a \mathop{:-} b$

$a \mathop{:\!-} b$

$a \mathop{:\!\!-} b$

%% suggested by Steven B. Seaglets

$a \mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{$:$}}-} b$

\end{document}
```

[image: various :-]

Comment: `\mathrel` rather than `\mathop`?

Comment: Yep, maybe. I really do not know what it means...